# Randomness in a nested pure function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, purely-functional

I want to provide a function that replaces each occurrence of `#` in a string with a different random number. In a non-pure language, it's trivial. However, how should it be designed in a pure language? I don't want to use `unsafePerformIO`, as it rather looks like a hack and not a proper design.

Should this function require a random generator as one of its parameters? And if so, would that generator have to be passed through the whole stack of invocations? Are there other possible approaches? Should I use the `State` monad, here? I would appreciate a toy example demonstrating a viable approach...

Comment: Since your first thought is to jump to a monad, you will like [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom).

Comment: "that generator would have to be passed through the whole stack of invocations" - that's a good thing. I want to _know_ which functions are impure. A function that uses randomness is not pure; Haskell deals with this by explicitly passing a random number generator around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would, in fact, use a variant of the state monad to pass the random generator around behind the scenes. The `Rand` type in `Control.Monad.Random` helps with this. The API is a bit confusing, but more because it's polymorphic over the type of random generator you use than because it has to be functional. This extra bit of scaffolding is useful, however, because you can easily reuse your existing code with different random generators which lets you test different algorithms as well as explicitly controlling whether the generator is deterministic (good for testing) or seeded with outside data (in `IO`).

Here's a simple example of `Rand` in action. The `RandomGen g =>` in the type signature tells us that we can use *any* type of random generator for it. We have to explicitly annotate `n` as an `Int` because otherwise GHC only knows that it has to be *some* numeric type that can be generated and turned into a string, which can be one of multiple possible options (like `Double`).

```
randomReplace :: RandomGen g => String -> Rand g String
randomReplace = foldM go ""
  where go str '#' = do
          n :: Int <- getRandomR (0, 10)
          return (str ++ show n)
        go str chr = return $ str ++ [chr]
```

To run this, we need to get a random generator from somewhere and pass it into `evalRand`. The easiest way to do this is to get the global system generator which we can do in `IO`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do gen <- getStdGen
          print $ evalRand (randomReplace "ab#c#") gen
```

This is such a common pattern that the library provides an `evalRandIO` function which does it for you:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do res <- evalRandIO $ randomReplace "ab#c#"
          print res
```

In the end, the code is a bit more explicit about having a random generator and passing it around, but it's still reasonably easy to follow. For more involved code, you could also use `RandT`, which allows you to extend other monads (like `IO`) with the ability to generate random values, letting you relegate all the plumbing and setup to one part of your code.

Comment: The thing that annoys me about randomness in Haskell is that using the same code for both pseudo-random and truly random numbers seems to pretty much require lazy I/O, which is widely shunned. If you commit to pseudo-random numbers and then later decide to switch to truly random ones, things get pretty icky. Perhaps `pipes` or `conduit` or some arrowy library offers a good solution; I don't know.

Comment: thanks. but what about nesting? now you're calling this function directly from IO monad. if we want to call this function from another function then we would have to make that function have type X -> Rand g Y, right?

Comment: Yes, the return type would have to be in `Rand`. The advantage of being a monad is that we can combine functions of the type `a -> Rand g b` easily without making the underlying plumbing explicit. This lets us use the types to mark which functions depend on randomness (we can't return a `b` directly because it would lose this information) without too much hassle in actually putting it together.

Comment: @piotrek The point is that all of the functions involved in the other layers of nested calls are *also* dependent on (and affecting) the random generator state; being explicit about this in the types is a good thing. The functional programming approach to this challenge is to come up with abstractions that make it easy to work these kinds of functions (like Monads). The imperative programming approach to this challenge is to make the information flow implicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a monadic mapping

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Random
import Data.Char

randomReplace :: RandomGen g => String -> Rand g String
randomReplace = mapM f where
    f '#' = intToDigit <$> getRandomR (0, 10)
    f  c  = return c

main = evalRandIO (randomReplace "#abc#def#") >>= print
```